# Call mencoder from Fortran or gnuplot

Tags: fortran, gnuplot, fortran90, mencoder

I have made a Fortran program thats plot a vector field with gnuplot, I want to make a animation of this. I have managed to print a 1000 pictures with the name framee_000000001.png, framee_000000002.png, framee_000000003.png and so on. Now i want to compile these pictures into a single movie. A user named bibi suggested i should use mencoder and gave me the following code: `mencoder mf://frame_%09d.png -mf fps=30 -ovc lavc -o my_video.avi`

I want to call on mencoder from Fortran or gnuplot, is this possible? In that case how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use system call which works fairly well depending on platform and compiler. For example you can call from fortran,

```
call system("mencoder mf://frame_%09d.png -mf fps=30 -ovc lavc -o my_video.avi")
```

Comment: note the modern standard fortran command is `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` (same usage)